# IE7: javascript canvas code used to work in IE7, now it doesn't. What happened between these two revisions that caused that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, canvas, raphael

Been working with the canvas element with a library called Raphael

Current revision: http://jsfiddle.net/G5mTx/27/
Working in IE7 revision: http://jsfiddle.net/G5mTx/10/

Note: These work in non-IE browsers.

So... I've added a bunch of jQuery handlers since revisions 10. Is there a javascript library I can use for just IE that will enable everything?

EDIT: Note that revisions 11-26 may not have to do with revisions 10 and 27 (jsfiddle is public)

Comment: In actual fact, Raphael uses SVG (or VML in IE 6/7/8) to do its drawing, not the Canvas element (even though the library uses the name 'Canvas' for its object). Also, your "current revision" looks quite broken to me in Firefox 3.6 / Linux.

Comment: shoot. well, I assume if it works in chrome, it works in the rest of the modern browsers. I guess only webkit supports height: 100%. I'll check again in IE. Here is current rev: http://jsfiddle.net/G5mTx/28/

Comment: oh hey, that fixed it! ... finding a new way to do the height should be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in comments of original post.